# unittest working in PyCharm but unable to run from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-unittest

I'm trying to run a unit test in the command line to generate code coverage. I can run the command from PyCharm fine, but running it from command line doesn't work.

The test is in a testing folder like the following

`a/b/c/testing/UnitTest.py`

The files I import are imported in the format

`from a.b.c.main.classes import MyClass`

If I try and directly run the unit test from the folder, it tells me that it can't import module a.

I'm fairly certain that PyCharm is fixing this issue because I have the boxes "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" checked, but I can't figure out how to do something equivalent in the command line.

How can I either fix my imports so it doesn't require it to be run from the root level, or add the content and source roots to PYTHONPATH so I can run in the command line?

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, `export PYTHONPATH=<full path to the root of your project>` before the test run should do the trick.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment and have you activated your environment? If so, it's usually convenient to do a `pip install -e .` in the root of your project to make it importable but still editable.

Comment: @aikikode, so that does work, but we use `os.getcwd()` in the code. Adding the PYTHONPATH there seems to cause the current directory to get set to root instead of the testing folder which makes it difficult to load in the files used in the tests. The tests then all fail because of the directory being in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are on Windows,

```
set PYTHONPATH=<Path to your Source folder >
```

for linux,

```
export PYTHONPATH=<Path to your Source folder >
```

once you set that running below command from project folder should do the work

```
python -m unittest discover
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd project_dir
python -m unittest -v a/b/c/testing/UnitTest.py -k your_test_name
```

-v is for unittest verbose log output.